# Aligning rows to same place in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap, and I am trying to align a logo and navbar to in the same line. Actually, in the image you see below. I want the menus, logo and navbar to start from the same point.

[image]

I know how the 12 grid-system works. But how do we make classes nested inside the rows to indent properly.

This is my HTML.

```
<section class="header-container jumbotron">
        <nav class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li> <a href="/"> HOME </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="pages/about"> ABOUT </a></li>
                <li> <a href="pages/register"> SUBMIT YOUR BUSINESS! </a></li>
                <li> <a href="pages/login"> LOGIN </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="pages/contact"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 logo">
            {{ HTML::image('img/logo.png', 'ethio360', array("height"=>44, "width"=>157))}}
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="search-bar col-md-12"> 

            {{ Form::open(['url'=>'/']) }}
                <div>
                    {{ Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
                    {{ Form::text('title') }}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {{ Form::label('body', 'Body') }}
                    {{ Form::text('body') }}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {{ Form::submit('Create Text')}}
                </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>

        </div>
</section>
```

The only thing I need is for the menu to appear first, then the logo and finally the searchbar. 
But they should all start from the same place from left. 
and this is my css.

```
.jumbotron{
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header-container{
    min-height: 325px;
    background: #ffd106; 
    background: url(../img/city.jpg);
    border-top:1px solid #252525;
}

.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li a{
    color:#252525;
    float:left;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:1px 10px;
}

.logo{
    padding:10px;
}

.search-bar{
    width:80%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #252525;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #545454;
    padding:5px 4px;
    color:#efefef;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.search-bar div{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.search-bar div input{
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    padding:4px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: I see you are using class `col-md-offset-2` in the navbar and the logo, but not in the search bar. Could this be the problem?

Comment: No I tried for both it is the same

Comment: Not sure about that, but I think when you use an `offset` class, the offset counts as if it were real columns, so you should not use `col-md-12` and `col-md-offset-2` in the same element because then the total count would be 14. It should be, for example, `col-md-10 col-md-offset-2`. See [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). BTW, which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Here is what I don't understand about offsets. What if I wanted to center `col-md-6` then If do I use offset to apply `col-md-3` on both sides, so that `col-md-6` can be centered?

Comment: the example in the documentation addresses exactly this case. If you want a column of 6 columns width, and you want it centered, you use classes `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`. The offset applies to the left side only.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your layout:

- You are defining columns in which the column width plus the offset is greater than 12.
- You are not putting columns inside rows.

I've put up a fiddle to illustrate a possible solution. Each of the three main elements (navbar, logo and search bar) is placed within its own row, and all of them have an offset of 2.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/N6chc/4/embedded/result/)

HTML:

```
<section class="header-container jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li> <a href="/"> HOME </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="pages/about"> ABOUT </a></li>
                <li> <a href="pages/register"> SUBMIT YOUR BUSINESS! </a></li>
                <li> <a href="pages/login"> LOGIN </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="pages/contact"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 logo">
            <span style="border: 1px solid gray;">Here goes the logo</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="search-bar col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"> 

            <form>
                <div>
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" "#title"/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <input type="text" "#body"/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create text"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header-container{
    min-height: 325px;
    background: #ffd106; 
    background: url(../img/city.jpg);
    border-top:1px solid #252525;
}

.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li a{
    color:#252525;
    float:left;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:1px 10px;
}

.logo{
    padding:10px;
}

.search-bar{
    width:80%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #252525;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #545454;
    padding:5px 4px;
    color:#efefef;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.search-bar div{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.search-bar div input{
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    padding:4px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code.

- You have not wrapped your columns in a row
- Your using a col-md-12 with an offset of 2, which adds up to 14
- You have a container nested inside another container
- You are not using an offset on the last div, so it would never align

Here's the code with those things changed.

```
    <section class="header-container jumbotron">
        <div class ='row'>
            <nav class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li> <a href="/"> HOME </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="pages/about"> ABOUT </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="pages/register"> SUBMIT YOUR BUSINESS! </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="pages/login"> LOGIN </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="pages/contact"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 logo">
                {{ HTML::image('img/logo.png', 'ethio360', array("height"=>44, "width"=>157))}}
            </div>

                <div class="search-bar col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"> 

                {{ Form::open(['url'=>'/']) }}
                    <div>
                        {{ Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
                        {{ Form::text('title') }}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        {{ Form::label('body', 'Body') }}
                        {{ Form::text('body') }}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        {{ Form::submit('Create Text')}}
                    </div>
                {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: if all columns inside a row are supposed to account to 12, then why do you have `nav class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2` and `col-md-4 col-md-offset-2` and `search-bar col-md-10` which makes a total of 28 columns inside one row.